# Laravel 5: Why loaded images file size are bigger than actual size on disk?

Tags: php, laravel, performance, laravel-5

I've been trying to optimize images on a Laravel 5 project.

I've used TinyPNG to compress images in the project. After compressing the images, the file size drop something like from 195kb to 67kb.

However, when doing performance testing, I found that time images are still the problem.

I found that the images still have the original file size (195kb) when loading on the website, according the Chrome Developer Tool.

I wonder why the images file size is smaller on disk, but bigger on browser load.

Note: I run php artisan clear:cache, view:clear, and config:clear. Also, disabled server cache and CDN.

My code is listed bellow

```
    $images = glob("" . $directory . "*.png");
    foreach ( $images as $image ){
        $optimized = Tinify::fromFile($image);
        $optimized->toFile($image);
    }
```

Comment: so.. there is one item to be cleared, some image compression does not always result in smaller image... you had to try to upload your image manually into tinypng yourself to see if it actually gets smaller or not.

Comment: @BagusTesa, I did that both using tinypng and other image compressor. Also, manually compress the images with Adobe Photoshop. I've never faced that issue before so what I'm concerning is the Laravel cache problem. Then, I've set the cache to 'none' in .env file, but unfortunately, it's still now working.

Comment: Do you still have the issue if you open the site in a Guest or Incognito window in Chrome?  You've cleared the Laravel cache, but what about the browser cache?

Comment: @matticustard, yes. I've tried Incognito window and all you said, but it doesn't work.